# glassfish gives an illegalstateexception - trying to deploy java ee timer application

Tags: java-ee-6

I have a simple application. Just one EJB with @startup and @singleton annotation. It programmitcally creates a timer and has a @timeout method. The code is mostly from the java ee 6 tutorial on the oracle website. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.Timer;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class TimerSessionBean {
    @Resource
    TimerService timerService;

    long duration = 6000;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(
            "simpletimer.service.TimerSessionBean");

    @PostConstruct
    public void setTimer() {
        logger.info("Setting a programmatic timeout for "
                + duration + " milliseconds from now.");
        Timer timer = timerService.createTimer(duration, 
                "Created new programmatic timer");
    }

    @Timeout
    public void programmaticTimeout(Timer timer) {
        logger.info("Programmatic timeout occurred.");
    }

}
```

Here is the error in the serverlog file:

```
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
```

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the server a couple of times and the error doesn't occur anymore. Still not sure what was wrong. I have a follow up question. I changes @Resource to @inject and it fails with javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton TimerSessionBean. What is the difference? I thought @inject should be used where possible? Thank you all.